# How to disable delete on table for certain id in h2?

Tags: sql, h2

Lets suppose we have `student` table in h2 and every student has id (primary key). Is it possible to implement trigger (or another mechanism) to disable delete operation if id == 100. I want to have such protection on DB level, but not on application level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is obviously a trigger that prevents deleting or changing the value.

Another method is to use a foreign key constraint.  Create a table of ids that you want to keep and use a foreign key reference:

```
create table keep_these_students (
    student_id int,
    constraint fk_keep_these_students_student_id foreign key (student_id) references students(id)
);

insert into keep_these_students (student_id)
    values (100);
```

The foreign key definition will require that the row cannot be deleted if the id changes.  And, it is easy to add additional ids -- without changing triggers.

Comment: This is a cute trick and much easier to maintain than a trigger.